# why I am unable to run this jar file of a maven project?

Tags: java, maven

Why I am unable to run this jar file? I clean and build the project successfully. but when I try to run the jar file in command prompt I get the error like

```
java -jar FSP-1.3.0 rc 1.jar

Error: Unable to access jarfile FSP-1.3.0
```

This is maven project done in netbeans IDE 7.2.1. Below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com.powerelectronics.freesun</groupId>
      <artifactId>FSP</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0 rc 1</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <name>FSPApp</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.10</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.4.v201112161009</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.1</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>au.com.alderaan</groupId>
          <artifactId>eclipselink-staticweave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <artifactId>maven-settings</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>

          <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.0</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.17</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax</groupId>
          <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
          <version>6.0</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1100-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
     </dependencies>
      <build>
          <plugins>
            <plugin> 
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId> 
                <executions> 
                    <execution> 
                        <phase>install</phase> 
                        <goals> 
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal> 
                        </goals> 
                        <configuration> 
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory> 
                        </configuration> 
                    </execution> 
                </executions> 
            </plugin> 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.application.SIA</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration> 
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                    <artifactId>eclipselink-staticweave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <groupId>au.com.alderaan</groupId>
                    <version>1.0.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>weave</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

             </plugin> 
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>EclipseLink</id>
                    <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </project>
```

Please reply me soon. Please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: java -jar FSP-1.3.0.jar rc 1.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is tripping about the spaces in your filename. Either rename your version from "1.3.0 rc 1" to something like "1.3.0-rc-1" or put the filename in quotes when calling java from the command-line:

> java -jar "FSP-1.3.0 rc 1.jar"

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options

1) As Joachim suggested put quotes around the jar file

```
java -jar "FSP-1.3.0 rc 1.jar"
```

2) Escape the spaces that exist in the jar name

```
java -jar FSP-1.3.0\ rc\ 1.jar
```

Both should work.